# How to pass a parameter to razor component in server-side Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

How can I pass parameter into razor component?

So far I tried

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Rateplan>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { id= 100}))
```

But I receive an error

> InvalidOperationException: Prerendering server components with
>   parameters is not supported.

I try the same thing with RenderMode.ServerPrerendered but I receive an error

> InvalidOperationException: Server components with parameters are not
>   supported.

I also tried doing

```
<Rateplan Id="100"></Rateplan>
```

but that didnt even start the component.

Comment: See also [this GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13721).

Comment: And also [this GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14433).

Answer (score 42):

In the component where you want to accept the parameter you need to have a Property marked as a parameter

Like

```
[Parameter]
public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
```

Then you should be able to pass in the parameter as

```
<Componentname Players="@players"></Componentname>
```

(In this example  @players is a local variable)

Comment: This is the correct answer, it was wrongly voted down. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-parameters

Comment: But only since ASP.NET Core 3.1. Additionally it does not answer the question, because the question is about rendering components using ` Html.RenderComponentAsync`.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question plus is outdated now... You don't need `param-Players` anymore, `Players` is enough now: `<Componentname Players="@players"></Componentname>`.

Comment: I am not up to date on the latest blazer anymore.
But you are welcome to suggest an edit if you say that the answer is outdated.

Also the question is:
"How to pass a parameter to razor component in server-side Blazor?" And this is/was an answer to that question.

He did never specify that it needed to be with the 
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Rateplan>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { id= 100}))

Just that he tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Set RenderMode as Static

```cs
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Rateplan>(RenderMode.Static, new { id = 100 }))
```

Comment: With the latest Blazor version (or since 3.1), this should work with `Server` and `ServerPrerendered` as well: `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Rateplan>(RenderMode.Server, new { id = 100 }))` and `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Rateplan>(RenderMode.ServerPreRendered, new { id = 100 }))`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem and workaround is described [in this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/10/02/blazor-gotchas.aspx). (There is a little bug, because `GetModel` should be named `GetCustomerId`)
Passing parameters is not supported, exactly as the Exception says.

You can wait for ASP.NET Core 3.1, [where the ability to pass parameters will be restored](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14433).

I have implemented the solution from the first article for parameter `OperationId` like this - razor component's code:

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

[Inject]
protected IJSRuntime jrt { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        try
        {
            var oid = await jrt.InvokeAsync<string>("GetOperationId");
            int opid;
            if (int.TryParse(oid, out opid))
                OperationId = opid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ls?.LogException(ex, "Sortiment.OnAfterRenderAsync");
        }
        //This code was moved from OnInitializedAsync which executes without parameter value
        if (OperationId.HasValue)
            sortiment = await ProductService.GetSortimentAsync(null, OperationId, Odpady);
        else
            productFilter = await ProductService.GetProductFilterAsync();
        StateHasChanged(); //Necessary, because the StateHasChanged does not fire automatically here
    }
}
```

and added this to the hosting Razor page:

```
@section Header
{
  <script>
  function GetOperationId() {
    return "@Model.OperationId";
  }
  </script>
}
```

This workaround works only for `RenderMode.Server`.

Answer (score 0):

How to pass the parameter (e.g. in Index.cshtml):

```
<component>@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>(RenderMode.Server, new { TeamID = Model.Team.ID }))</component>
```

MyComponent.razor:

```
@page "/myComponent"
@inject IDataAccess dataAccess;

<h1>@TeamID</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string TeamID { get; set; }

    public Team team { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        team = dataAccess.GetTeamByID(TeamID);
    }
}
```